# git: how to determine what I'm branched from

Tags: git

I'm working on a `dev` branch with a co-worker.

We have multiple release branches that we do dev work from.

Is there an easy way for me to see which release branch my coworker forked our dev branch from?

Right now when I'm in this situation I do a `git log --decorate` and look back through the history for the base branch.

If there's a command that finds this more programmatically for me, I'd like to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

First find the `<name>` of the current branch using:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

Do this on the branch for which you want to find the parent.

Next run:

```
git show-branch -a| grep  "\*"| grep -v "<name>"| head -n1|sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//'
```

This will give you the branch name.

Comment: Your answer implies that git has no mechanism to concisely get the branch you're forked from. I suppose that's the answer to my question, seeing as there are no other replies.

Comment: That's correct. As far as git is concerned you forked of a commit. Consider this, you can rename a branch after you forked from it. The name changed but the commit will stay the same.